# Angular 5 & ngx-Translate error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to install ngx-Translate to my app which use angular 5 but I get those errors.

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.0.0 invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.0.0 invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.0.0 invalid
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@5.0.0 invalid
```

I did not find an answer for this when I googled it.

Any help is highly appriciated

Comment: which version you install ?

Comment: the latest one using this command " npm install @ngx-translate/core --save "